# Highcharts - Line chart is using wrong TimeZone

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I have a situation where I need to display the exact time received from server in the Highchart. The datetime should not change based on either server timezone or client timezone.

I have set the UTC to true:

```
Highcharts.setOptions({
    global: {
        useUTC: true,
        timezoneOffset: 0
    }
});
```

And I am passing the Milliseconds as data:

```
    for (i = 0; i < xAxisData.length; i++) {
        item = xAxisData[i];
        dateMiliseconds = parseInt(item.DateTime.replace('/Date(', ''));
        var obj = { x: dateMiliseconds, title: item.FlagText, text: item.Text };
        xData.push(obj);
    }
```

then setting the series like this:

```
    $scope.chartConfig.series.push({
        type: 'flags',
        data: xData,
        onSeries: 'mileageSeries',
        shape: 'squarepin',
        name: 'Events',
        title: 'Events',
        id: "Events"
        //width: 16
    });
```

Now everything works fine if I have server with UTC date time system settings.

[image]

But when I have a server with UTC + 5 date time system settings the graph is wrong:

[image]

What I need is no matter what the server timezone is and no matter what the Client side timezone is it should display `7:42`. 7:42 time is sent from the server in both cases the data is same:

```
   DateTime: "/Date(1453776133000)/"
   DateTimeString: "26/01/2016 07:42:13"
```

Comment: You probably need to set a dynamic TZ offset, see http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.7.2/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/highcharts/global/gettimezoneoffset/

Answer (score 1):

I'm maybe wrong, but the problem isn't that you are using UTC ? By setting useUTC to false, I think you will use the exact value of your datetime, whatever is your server/client time zone

Comment: When I set UTC to false then the UTC time server adds another 5 hours to the date

Answer (score 1):

You can set the timezone that Highcharts should using as follow:

```
Highcharts.setOptions(global : {
    timezoneOffset: 180
});
```

`timezoneOffset` uses the time in minutes

Comment: why set the timezoneOffset to 180?

Comment: Because it is my timezone : p (-03:00)

Comment: I don't understand how it will fix the issue. You are saying I should add the TimeZone of the client?

Comment: As far as I know, you have to set a timezone in Highcarts equals to your timezone in the server to make it works like you want. I'm just showing how to set it in the client side

Comment: I'm facing this problem again... I found a nice link http://blog.ninjamedia.com.au/the-useutc-flag-in-highcharts/

Comment: @RafaelTeles your nice link is a deadlink now, I feel that they use UTC by default in highstock charts, and somehow I can't override it by setting UTC to false, bizarre...

Answer (score 0):

Alternative to @Rafael Teles's solution is setting timezone as a string.

```
const timezone: string = Intl.DateTimeFormat().resolvedOptions().timeZone;

Highcharts.setOptions({
    time: {
        timezone: timezone
    }
});
```

The DateTimeFormat() function returns the timezone as a string, for example ''Europe/Oslo''

https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/time.timezone